# Where to locate the folder created by Docker during build

Tags: docker, dockerfile

I have the following experimental Dockerfile:

```
FROM python:3.11
WORKDIR /usr/src/app
RUN pwd
RUN ls -l
COPY requirements.txt ./
RUN ls -l


RUN pip install --no-cache-dir -r requirements.txt

COPY . .

CMD [ "python", "-u", "subscriber.py" ]
```

When I start the docker build using `--progress=plain` and `--no-cache`, then during the build process, I can see the output of the `pwd` command as `/usr/src/app` and I can see the contents of the folder on the console. Before copying the `requirements.txt` file, the folder is empty and after copy, the folder contents list the file.

But in the file system on my OS, if I navigate to `/usr/src`, I cannot find any folder named `app`
So where does Docker create that folder? Or does it create it during the build process and later delete it?

This is a newbie question, and I am pretty new to Docker, so please bear with the question.

The Linux version is: Ubuntu 22.04.2 LTS

EDIT 1:

From the thread: [What is "/app" working directory for a Dockerfile?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/55108649/what-is-app-working-directory-for-a-dockerfile), I understand that the WORKDIR is created inside the container image. But when I connect to the container shell, I cannot find the directory there either.

Answer (score 0):

When you are in the docker container, it is a completely new file system, unrelated to the file system on your actual computer. The point of docker is to create this separate container that only has the specifications you provide it in your "Dockerfile" config.

Comment: So where is the folder created during the build process? A container is created only when I run the docker. So if I run the docker image and if I log on to the shell of the container, will I find the /usr/src/app folder?

Comment: Yes, when you run the docker image that you have created, you will be put into the WORKDIR directory, `docker run -it <image> /bin/bash` will give you an interactive shell and you will be in the directory /usr/src/app.

I think you are somehow connecting to the container shell incorrectly.